# Calculate Binomial Probability for inequality

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

How could the binomial probability be calculated for a case of
$P(X \geq 2)$
for a given value of $n$ and $p$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the usual sort of set up, easiest might be $$P(X≥2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)=1-(1-p)^n-np(1-p)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Then for a case like $P(X\geq 1)$, would it simply be 1 ?

Comment: No.  $P(X≥1)=1-P(X=0)$.